# Xamarin.Forms Animation for multiple controls in parallel

Tags: c#, xamarin, animation, xamarin.forms

For my Xamarin.Forms project I need to animate two Xamarin Frame items in parallel, but I just don't understand [the example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/Animation/Custom/AnimationDemo/ColorAnimationPage.xaml.cs)  where they use:

```
async void OnAnimateLabelButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
    await Task.WhenAll(
        label.ColorTo(Color.Red, Color.Blue, c => label.TextColor = c, 5000),
        label.ColorTo(Color.Blue, Color.Red, c => label.BackgroundColor = c, 5000));
...
}
```

`Task.WhenAll` which - in my humble opinion - does not guarantee that it runs on the GUI main thread, as no `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` is to be seen.

According to this [forums.xamarin.com](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53527/animate-multiple-views-in-parallel) entry, the preferred way to use multiple animations at a time is via:

```
Animation a = new Animation();
a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(f => this.GuidanceLabel.Opacity = f, 1, 0, Easing.SinInOut, null));
a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(f => this.EnableAccess.Opacity = f, 1, 0, Easing.SinOut, null));
a.Commit(
    owner:this.GuidanceLabel,
    name:"DoubleFader",
    length:400,
    finished:(x, y) => 
    {
        this.SetPhotoAccessDeniedState();
        this.GuidanceLabel.FadeTo(1, 400, Easing.CubicIn);
    });
```

So, I suppose, I have to wrap my animation in a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` to make it work properly, and for my special animation case, the workflow would be:

```
Frame1.TranslateYto (-90, duration1);
Frame1.Content.IsVisible = true; // Was formerly false
Frame1.TranslateYto (0, duration2);
```

And for *Frame2* the same in parallel.

So I have tried:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Animation a = new Animation();
    a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(v => frame1.RotationY = v, 0, -90));
    a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(v => frame2.RotationY = v, 0, -90));
    a.Commit(
        owner: frame1,
        name: "flip1",
        length: 50,
        finished: (x, y) =>
        {
                frame1.Content.IsVisible = false;
                frame2.Content.IsVisible = false;
        });

    a = new Animation();
    a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(v => frame1.RotationY = v, -90, 0));
    a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(v => frame2.RotationY = v, -90, 0));
    a.Commit(
        owner: frame1,
        name: "flip2",
        length: 250);
});
```

But it crashes with a *NullReferenceExecption*...

Maybe someone can shed some more light on the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add two Frame control in window and create same animation as you, but I don't have any issue. Here is my code.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Frame
            x:Name="frame1"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Text="this is test!!!!!!!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </Frame>

        <Frame x:Name="frame2" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Text="this is test22222222222222!!!!!!!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </Frame>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="50"
            Text="btn1"
            WidthRequest="300" />
    </StackLayout>

 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            Animation a = new Animation();
            a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(v => frame1.RotationY = v, 0, -90));
            a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(v => frame2.RotationY = v, 0, -90));
            a.Commit(
                    owner: frame1,
                    name: "flip1",
                    length: 50,
                    finished: (x, y) =>
                    {
                        frame1.Content.IsVisible = false;
                        frame2.Content.IsVisible = false;
                    });

            a = new Animation();
            a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(v => frame1.RotationY = v, -90, 0));
            a.Add(0, 1, new Animation(v => frame2.RotationY = v, -90, 0));
            a.Commit(
                    owner: frame1,
                    name: "flip2",
                    length: 250);

        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clearifying! The  nasty null ref exception came from an ancient corner of my code base :)